# Multiplication of numbers from a to b

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, multiplication

I need to write algorithm, that multiplies numbers from a to b without input (scanf). Like this:

```
a = 2;
b = 6;

2 * 3
2 * 4
...
2 * 6
```

I have my algorithm:

```
void main()
{
    int dist = 1;
    int a = 2;
    int b = 5;
    for (int i = a; a <= b; a++) {
        printf("%d", a * a++);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work correct

Comment: The assignment seem to be to multiply the *original* value of `a` with an **i**ndex counting up. Does your code do that? I suggest you print the values of `a`, `b` and `i` inside the loop, and wait with any other calculations until you can get the values of all variables correct first.

Comment: The question is clearly lacking clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are increasing a (`a++`) two times in your example above. Also you mixed up `a` and `i` a little bit. Correct one is:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 5;
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
{
    printf("%d * %d = %d\n", a, i, a * i);
}
```

which prints:

> 2 * 2 = 4
>
> 2 * 3 = 6
>
> 2 * 4 = 8
>
> 2 * 5 = 10

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude A previous version of this answer did that, I assume that's what emblox tested.